# Zoom ring clicks after dropping my Canon 18-55mm IS II kit lens; what to do?

Tags: equipment-damage, kit-lens

I recently dropped my Canon EOS 600D attached to the 18-55mm IS II lens inside the Canon camera bag from a height of 3ft, and the zoom ring after that is really tight, and I hear a clicking sound when I rotate it, but the auto focus seems to work fine. What can I do now?

Answer (score 2):

The 18-55 is too cheap to repair.

Options:

1) use it as is
2) buy a new one, they sell for about $120
3) buy a 17-55 F2.8 (for $1200)
4) buy a 50mm f1.8 for $120

Comment: if i were to repair it any idea how much it would cost me ?? and what might be the problem?  ty

Comment: Any lens repair will start at about $95 just to have the technician look at it. You are already at the replacement price. Any parts and labor to fix it are above that. Its simply not worth considering fixing it.  You might also look at the 40mm F2.8 STM, its a nice all around lens for an APS-C camera

Comment: @PatFarrell In Australia Canon repair center charges $50 AUD to quote for repair. Not sure where that $95 comes from...

Comment: Wow, one of the few things cheaper in AU than here. $95 is the standard price on the east coast in the US.  However the fundamental point holds, $50 for a quote is without doing any work. Since the lens sells for roughly $100 new, they are unrepairable. Just like a toaster.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford it, this is a good chance for you to upgrade to a worthy lens, with bigger aperture.

The cheapest option is Sigma 18-50 F2.8-4.5 HSM OS. $250. Even better is fixed aperture F2.8 for 600$, but as you can see the price jump is substantial.

I have heard good about Tamron's fixed aperture version 17-50mm F2.8 for $500 (not VC, which is significantly worse), but in general I am not impressed by their build quality - I have held more than one Tamron's (owned by friends) that after 1-2 years go "crunch crunch" when you focus it. Never have I seen that with Canon and Sigma, or even 30-60y old vintage lenses.

People worry about non-Canon AF performance, but my Sigmas perform equal or better than my Canons.

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with another lens. Warranty coverage includes defects in materials and workmanship, but does not usually extend to user damage.

You can pick up a used EF-S 18-55mm IS II lens at Adorama for about $80-125, or a new one for about $200 on Amazon. It would probably cost more to repair the one you've got.
Other options would be lenses such as:

Tamron 17-50mm f/2.8 Di II (non-VC or VC version)

Sigma 17-50mm f/2.8 EX DC OS HSM

Sigma 17-70mm f/2.8-4 DC Macro OS

Canon EF-S 18-135mm f/3.5-5.6 IS

Canon EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM Lens

Canon EF-S 17-85mm f/4-5.6 IS USM Lens

Comment: one thing to note is that sigma 17-70mm looks good on paper, but reviews seems disappointed

Comment: Also tamrons VC version is significantly worse than the other version.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen: I've always heard that, and even said it a few times myself. But have you compared the two at DxO Mark? The VC is sharper in the center at wider apertures, the non-VC is sharper by the corners. Above f/4 there is no real difference. I think the QC difference within either lens model is greater than the difference between two good copies of each model. Click on measurements->sharpness->profiles. http://www.dxomark.com/index.php/Lenses/Compare-Camera-Lenses/Compare-lenses/%28lens1%29/497/%28brand%29/Tamron/%28camera1%29/0/%28lens2%29/185/%28brand2%29/Tamron/%28camera2%29/0

Comment: Ive seen the mouse-overs on the "digital picture" and both CA and blur is crazy on the crops from the VC version, while the nonVC looks more like Sigma EX and Canon

Comment: I've seen it too. He might have gotten a copy that was lousy. When he gets an out-of-whack Canon lens he gets another couple of copies. He didn't mention doing that with the Tamron VC lens, for which he never finished the full review. The non-VC version had a reputation of wide variation from lens to lens. I got one that was razor sharp, but not everyone did.

Answer (score 2):

Well. There's a few things you can do in cases like these:

- You can keep using it until it breaks well and truly (there's a small chance it will cause damage to your camera though if something breaks off and scratches the sensor say),
- You can get a quote for repairs from canon or a 3rd party (considering the cost of a new(or secondhand) lens i wouldn't advise it)
- You could try and repair it yourself, if the lens is a write off it might be an interesting project
- You can sell the lens as 'for parts' online and get a few bucks for it, maybe someone else has repair skills of wants to use parts in a project.
- You can buy a replacement or you can upgrade

Hope that helps!